# Split sentence into words pandas and keep tags

Tags: python, pandas, named-entity-recognition, sentence

I have a Pandas dataframe like

```
Text                  label      value
board members         A1          NaN
a really long sent    A2          B2
```

**Result:** I would like to unnest the sentences and keep each label per word-split, like this

```
Sentence    Text         label      value
   1        board          A1        NaN
   1        members        A1        NaN
   2          a            A2        B2
   2        really         A2        B2 
   2         long          A2        B2 
   2         sent          A2        B2
```

Extra: If possible, I would like to extract a POS (Part of Speech) tagging of each word in a new column_

```
Sentence    Text         label      value    POS
   1        board          A1        NaN     Something
   1        members        A1        NaN     Something
   2          a            A2        B2      Something
   2        really         A2        B2      etc
   2         long          A2        B2 
   2         sent          A2        B2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `Text` to list then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.split()
df = df.explode("Text")

print(df)

      Text        label value
0    board  A1            NaN
0  members  A1            NaN
1        a  A2             B2
1   really  A2             B2
1     long  A2             B2
1     sent  A2             B2
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Do you have any suggestion of tagging part of speech of a Pandas column?

Comment: @TooManyRightHands, you need [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)

Comment: @TooManyRightHands try using spacy library for POS tagging