# How to add the processed text (token of words) column back to its original table using python

Tags: python, pandas, token

I would like to perform text analysis like world cloud and ngram on one of the text columns. I have broken down the sentence into tokens and want to join back it to the original table.
For example here are my two rows:

```
      Code              Text 
      ST-441          Purpose of your visit mentioned
      St-432           Describe how and where it happened
```

after doing text cleaning on the text column I applied the following function

After applying the split function the sentence has broken down into words, one row has become n rows and wants to add it back to the original table using a unique identifier column.

```py
def cleans(data):
    tokens = list(map(lambda data: data.split(' '), text))
```

Now I got the list of tokens like 'purpose', 'your', 'visit', 'mentioned', 'described' ...

I am looking for the below output

```
 Code              Text 
 ST-441          Purpose
 ST-441          your
 ST-441          Visit
 ST-441          mentioned
 ST-432          Describe
 ST-432          how
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide more info. How have you used the apply method? I do not see it used in your code. Having said that, you do not use the apply method to append rows to a dataframe. You should at least do a basic search on that first. A starting point is :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916371/how-to-append-new-row-to-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Galo do Leste I have edited the question. Hope it helps in understanding my issue better.

Comment: Where did `St-432` go?  And how/why is `of` exlcuded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split sentence into words pandas and keep tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313590/split-sentence-into-words-pandas-and-keep-tags)

Comment: I have added ST_432, but because of the limited characters, I dint add it earlier. Also, I have removed stop words in the text cleaning process hence there is no 'of'. @MatBailie